# Image.FromStream throws OutOfMemory exception when loading PNG. JPG works fine

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, png, microsoft-dynamics

I'm developing a dynamics crm plugin where I need to load an image from stream.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray))
{
    using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(ms)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When i read the bytearray from an .jpg-file everything works fine.

But when I read it from a png-file I get an OutOfMemory exception.
I tried several png-files they were smaller than the jpgs (just a few kb).

I validated the first 4 bytes and they are correct (jpg/png depending on the file I was reading).

I used the same code and png-files outside a plugin in a simple test-cmd-tool and there it works fine.

Any ideas??

Best Regards

Comment: PNG , jpg and bmp each are its own image file formats. You cannot process the bytes array just as it is in another format, you will need some conversion module classes.

Comment: `bitmap.RawFormat` to be checked and the rest of your code need to appropriately do whatever it is doing with the image stream.

Comment: sorry you got me wrong. the byte-array has the correct type. I checked the first bytes and they are valid. In one case the byte-array is an jpg --> works. the other byte-array is an png --> exception

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran I cannot check the bitmap.RawFormat because the constructor, where I pass the stream throws the exception already

Comment: Check the place where you get that bytes array, may be something amiss there. are you sure you are using the Bitmap class from System.Drawing namespace? May be this class is from some other namespace and has issues with png file format.

Comment: yes I'm sure. I also put a static base64-string in the sourcecode, converted this to an byte[] and this crashed, too...

Comment: I would suggest trying saving the byte array to disk and open it with some third party program to verify that the data is valid. As far as I know, system.Drawing.Bitmap should look at the file signature to determine the format, so I would expect the above code to work. I.e. is it possible the error is somewhere else?

Comment: from your tests looks like a dynamics crm plugin issue. Did you try with Image instead of Bitmap? (if what you want to do is achievable also using the Image class of course)

Comment: yes tried that, too. Didn't work either